# VS-code shows import errors when project is in root directory

Tags: reactjs, linux, visual-studio-code, npm, yarn-v2

```
OS - Linux Mint
Machine - ThinkPad 13 2nd Gen
Shell: zsh 5.8.1
DE: Cinnamon 5.6.8 
CPU: Intel i5-7200U (4) @ 3.100GHz 
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 620 
Memory: 9328MiB / 15887MiB
```

I am working on a react project that requires me to use yarn v3.3.0.

Unfortunately, Linux mint encrypts the home directory and thus yarn does not work properly when the project is in home directory.

I can add the following lines to the .yarnrc.yml file

```
enableGlobalCache: true

nodeLinker: node-modules
```

or

```
cacheFolder: /yarn/cache

nodeLinker: node-modules
```

where /yarn/cache is a folder in root dir with ownership to $USER:$USER

or

```
# make a symlink to a folder /yarn/cache in root dir in .yarn folder
nodeLinker: node-modules
```

but, That comes with other problems and makes creating merge requests harder.

Everything else works fine. But vs-code doesn't seems to like this. Is there a way to make vs-code find the imports ?

Everything else works fine. But vs-code doesn't seems to like this. Is there a way to make vs-code find the imports ?

P.S. It would be perfect if I didn't need to move to the root dir. BUT I think solution like that is too much to ask.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.config/Code/User
```

This seems to solve the problem.